# alternate look for the GNOME main menu

Tags: gnome, panel

On my desktop computer, the GNOME main menu on the panel has a different look: it's just one "Ubuntu logo" icon; clicking on it displays the "Applications" menu on top, with "Resources" and "System" being two sub-menus (last two entries).

I actually like this alternate style more than the default one, and would like to have it on my laptop as well.  What should I set/alter to have the alternate look on another computer?

(The desktop has always been this way -- I guess it's because it was a Debian machine before, and I installed Ubuntu without reformatting `/home`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Right click on the panel.
2. Click 'Add to Panel...'.
3. Select 'Main Menu' (not 'Menu Bar', this is the default menu applet).
4. Click 'Add'.

You can remove the old menu by right clicking it and clicking 'Remove from Panel'.